# Android apk build error

Tags: android, android-multidex

Please help me resolve the following issue.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\...\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [C:\...\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\69.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [69.jar:org/intellij/lang/annotations/Flow.class]))
```

I depend on only some Play Services libraries as follows:

```
// Play services
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"
//Firebase
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${rootProject.ext.playServicesVersion}"
```

Comment: Try Cleaning if still there then invalidate cache and restart!

Comment: try to check the dependencies of App and Module Lib App and make sure any lib dependencies is not define twice with other version name.

Comment: @Xenolion didn't help

Comment: checked dependencies with `gradle -q dependencies` and everything seems fine. No idea where to look for a solution

Comment: Please answer your own question using the Answer field below instead of editing it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a kotlin conflict with an annotation library. Replacing it with `com.google.support.annotations` did the trick for me.

Comment: Yes i have the same problem too with `'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'` and it's fixed after i change to `"com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"`